# Graying out non-used code in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

im currently working on a project that has platform-specific code in it.

I would like eclipse to gray out code-areas that are not active based on the defines for my project.
For example:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
/* 'type cast' : conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' of greater size */
#pragma warning(disable : 4306)
/* conditional expression is constant: introduced by FD_SET(..) */
#pragma warning(disable : 4127)
/* non-constant aggregate initializer: issued due to missing C99 support */
#pragma warning(disable : 4204)
/* padding added after data member */
#pragma warning(disable : 4820)
/* not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' */
#pragma warning(disable : 4668)
/* no function prototype given: converting '()' to '(void)' */
#pragma warning(disable : 4255)
/* function has been selected for automatic inline expansion */
#pragma warning(disable : 4711)
#endif
```

This code is only active when using the MS compiler and i want it to be grayed when _MSC_VER is not defined.

How can i achieve this?
Im running eclipse on ubuntu, if it matters.

Comment: On my machine, by default, it is greyed out as shown by this screenshot:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/4TL4J.png

To ensure your code is disabled, you need to make sure the scanner is configured correctly.

Can you provide more info on your setup. Eclipse version for example?

Answer (score 1):

Found it out myself:
Eclipse activated scalability mode and deactivated the indexer.